# How do you select elements by class based on a value in a text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to / How would you select elements by class defined from input from a text field?

The example is:

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div class="abc"></div>
<div class="def"></div>
<div class="def"></div>
<div class="abc"></div>
```

Pseudo-jquery:

```
$("#search").blur(function() {
    $('.class-of-what-was-typed-in-search-box').addClass(".highlight");
});
```

Comment: Use string concatenation

`$("#search").blur(function() {
    $('.' + this.value).addClass(".highlight");
});`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('.'+$("#search").val())
```